# Add additional data when django form is saved

Tags: django, django-forms

I am looking for some help in my first django app and I am new to programming. I have the below scenario:

**Models:**

```
class save_table(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   UniqueuserID = models.CharField(max_length=7)
   UserLocation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   UserLead = models.CharField(max_length=50)

   def __str__(Self):
      return self.UniqueuserID

class data_table(models.Model):
   UniqueuserID = models.CharField(max_length=7)
   name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   UserLocation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   UserLead = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**Form:**

```
class save_table_form(forms.ModelForm):
   
   class Meta:
      model = save_table
      fields = ('UniqueuserID')

   def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
      super(save_table_form,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

Every user ID that the user will add to the form will have a respective data entry int he second model and I want to save that additional data along with the form. However I did not use a foreign key because I do not want the saved model data in the save_table to change based on the changes in the data_table. Can I add the additional data to the form before saving the form.

```
if form.is_valid():
   form.save()
```

Please help..

Comment: Probably a better option is to use `post_save` signal to update `data_table` after `save_table` is updated. Or you can override model `save` method instead.

Comment: Can you help share some sample syntax of how to do that please..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add aditional data when saving the form!
overwrite the saving methoud in class save_table_form:
like this :

```
class save_table_form(forms.ModelForm):
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user_id = self.cleaned_data['id']
        user_photo = self.cleaned_data['photo']
        user_password = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        user = SysUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if user_password:
            user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.mobile = self.cleaned_data['mobile']
        user.office_id = self.cleaned_data['office_id']
        if user_photo:
            user.image = user_photo
        user.save()
        user.user_permissions.clear()
        user.user_permissions.add(*self.cleaned_data['user_permissions'])
        print('data is saving')
        return user
```

Comment: Thanks, ehsan.. Can you please advise what should be the user in my case? Thanks

Comment: I am confusing with your  schema !  first work with a simple model  example and then work on your case ; Karthik Viz